# Lebesgue density for other probability measures on $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

**Does the [Lebesgue density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) hold for arbitrary (Borel) probability measures on $[0,1]$?**

Following [Downey & Hirschfeldt's proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=FwIKhn4RYzYC&lpg=PA5&ots=_jfPX93OWj&dq=lebesgue%20density%20theorem%20downey%20hirschfeldt&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=lebesgue%20density%20theorem%20downey%20hirschfeldt&f=false) leads me to believe that the answer is "yes". (Recall every probability measure on $[0,1]$ is [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure), which is a key step in the proof.)

But I feel that if this is true, it would be easy to find it stated somewhere, though I've not been able to. All proofs, statements, mentions, etc. that I've seen regard only the Lebesgue measure. (I've looked in Royden's, Folland's, and Billingsley's books in addition to Downey & Hirschfeldt's.)

**If it does hold, is there a good reason why it's received so little attention (if it indeed has)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it seems hard to find, perhaps that is because the proof uses technical covering arguments that authors don't wish to get into. Nevertheless proofs are written down in several places. See e.g. chapter 2 in *Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces* by Mattila.

Comment: What a great reference. Thanks much.